# Solution for apple's objection&rejection on our GPS based app?

Tags: ios, gps, appstore-approval

We are developing an app that share user location on the map when they login and others can tap on their profile pic on map and start chatting with them .
Apple rejected the app with following reply :

"17.1 - Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used.

Upon further review, we found that your app enables the display of nearby users’ locations on a map but only prompts users on sign up or sign in for permission to show their location. If the user has signed in and previously agreed, then they are not prompted again until they log out. This is not appropriate for the App Store.

Specifically, it is not appropriate to display the user's location automatically without the option to decline if they have already signed in to access your app." We already tried to add multiple popup/confirm boxes for user permissions. what should be done to take care of this privacy issue ?

Should we add a button to manually checkin , everytime they want to update thier location ? this will defeat the purpose though if they have to click a button to update location to show where they are .

Or

Should we ask for permission to Show location each time App is opened since apple's objection is that it don't ask for permission again untill user is logged out and log in back ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a speculative answer, since Apple has somewhat fuzzy replies, but this is my view:

> > Specifically, it is not appropriate to display the user's location automatically without the option to decline if they have already signed in to access your app."

You could solve it by:
* Sending a push notification when the user's location is being used (this could be annoying depending on app usage of location)
* Showing some info in a very visible place in the app, e.g. in the lateral menu, along with the option to reject to share your location (or otherwise, tell the user there that they can do so by logging out)

There must be other possible solutions, since the reviewer is a human being and the guideline broad and unspecific enough... But I think any of these options would work.